# Moving items between two lists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events

I want to move items between two lists. All list items have buttons within them, once this button is clicked, item should be moved to the other list. I have created JavaScript event but it works only one way - so the item can be moved once e.g. from list1 to list2 but when I try to click on the button again, it doesn't work. Can you look at me code and advise how can I assign my event also to newly created items (these that just have been moved)?

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".moveBtn");

    var list1 = document.getElementById("list1");

    var list2 = document.getElementById("list2");

        function moveItem(e) {
        var newItem = document.createElement("li");

        if (this.parentElement.parentElement.id === "list1") {
            list2.appendChild(newItem);


        } else {
            list1.appendChild(newItem);

        }

        newItem.innerHTML = this.parentElement.innerHTML;
        this.parentElement.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentElement);

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", moveItem);
    }

 })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than destroying the old element and creating a new one, just *move* the element:

```
function moveItem(e) {
    var moveTo = this.parentElement.parentElement.id == "list1" ? list2 : list1;
    moveTo.appendChild(this.parentElement);
}
```

Note also that there's no need to match on `id`; you can match on the actual element:

```
function moveItem(e) {
    var moveTo = this.parentElement.parentElement == list1 ? list2 : list1;
    moveTo.appendChild(this.parentElement);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".moveBtn");
    var list1 = document.getElementById("list1");
    var list2 = document.getElementById("list2");

    function moveItem(e) {
        var moveTo = this.parentElement.parentElement == list1 ? list2 : list1;
        moveTo.appendChild(this.parentElement);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", moveItem);
    }
});
```

```css
#list1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#list2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="list1">
  <div>
    Item 1
    <button class="moveBtn">Move</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    Item 2
    <button class="moveBtn">Move</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    Item 3
    <button class="moveBtn">Move</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="list2">
  <div>
    Item 4
    <button class="moveBtn">Move</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    Item 5
    <button class="moveBtn">Move</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    Item 6
    <button class="moveBtn">Move</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. Just to clarify - is appendChild itself changing the location of the child (so there is no need to create new element and remove the old one)?

Comment: @Joanna: Right, we're just moving the existing element from one parent to another. When you call `appendChild` (or any of the other methods that puts a child in a parent), it removes the element from any previous parent it had (if it had any).